# symfony4 access nested parameters

Tags: symfony4

I have few parameters related to AWS configuration, I need to get access to from my service. Usually, I'm injecting `ParameterBagInterface` to the service if I need few parameters and using it to get parameters I need, in such way I do not need to check if a parameter really exists and handle it on my own, as `ParameterBag` throwing `ParameterNotFoundException` if a parameter is not exist.

But to make `ParameterBag` working as I need, parameters in service.yml should be added like:

```
aws.default_one: '%env(AWS_DEFAULT_BUCKET)%' 
aws.default_two: '%env(AWS_DEFAULT_BUCKET)%'
```

and now I can get it from bag like this `$this->parameterBag->get('aws.default_one')`

But yml syntax allowing to add nested parameters, so I can add parameters to config like this:

```
aws:
    default_one: '%env(AWS_DEFAULT_BUCKET)%' 
    default_two: '%env(AWS_DEFAULT_BUCKET)%'
```

it looks much cleaner and more readable especially when you have a lot of parameters, but in such a way I can't just write `$this->parameterBag->get('aws.default_one')` (it will throw the error  **The parameter "aws.default_one" must be defined** ) and the only way to get it from parameters bag I found is `$this->parameterBag->get('aws')['default_one']` but then it makes no sense to use parameter bag at all as you still need to make validation by your own to check if `default_one` key exists and handle it. And in such case instead of passing whole parameter bag, I can just pass `%aws%` to the service and work with it as with php array.

So questions are:

- what is the best practice to inject a list of parameters to the
  service, inject parameter bag or just pass each parameter or array of
  nested parameters to the service?
- maybe there is some way to get nested parameter using dot notation instead of doing like `$this->parameterBag->get('aws')['default_one']` as it makes life easier with just using parameter bag which throwing exception?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, parameters are injected and defined in the arguments section of your service :

```
    App\Service\MyService:
    arguments:
        $config:
            access_token: '%env(resolve:ACCESS_TOKEN)%'
            environment: '%env(resolve:SPEC_ENV)%'
```

Here, I'm using environment parameters, but it doesn't really matters, you could use plain value.
If you need to inject multiple parameters :

```
    App\Service\MyService:
    arguments:
        $access_token: '%env(resolve:ACCESS_TOKEN)%'
        $environment: '%env(resolve:SPEC_ENV)%'
```

And your service definition will look like :

```
public function __construct($access_token, $environment)
{
    //...
}
```

Also from the documentation :

> The used . notation is a Symfony convention to make parameters easier to read. Parameters are flat key-value elements, they can't be organized into a nested array

What you are trying to do is a config tree, which is more appropriate for public bundles : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html

Comment: what If I in some service I need get access to many parameters (around 10) and they different per env and number of params can vary, I do not think it's a good idea to add all of them as constructor arguments separately... That why I want to use parameter bag, and asking if it supports access using dot notation. But as I see it can't.... so I need pass whole array as argument and add validation by my self. Thanks!

Comment: You could use the env folders, and yes you have to validate manually. And the doc is pretty clear that the dot is only a convention of naming.